# Some SWIFT Questions

Tags: c#-4.0, swift-mt

I hava some questions about [SWIFT](http://www.swift.com):

1. What database does SWIFT use and can I connect to it and insert messages to it?
2. If I can insert message in database can SWIFT send it?
3. Is it possible to send a message using SWIFT using other languages such C#, VB.NET or Delphi?
4. If the answer to number 3 is true I think SWIFT security is low. Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

SWIFT isn't a database - it's a messaging standard akin to EDI.

You can contact the SWIFT folks, and they can put you in touch with software vendors who supply software which can speak SWIFT.  Software like [Progress Artix Data Services](http://web.progress.com/en/artix-data-services/index.html), which can convert SWIFT messages into Java POJOs or map to databases like Oracle, MySQL and others.

I believe it is also a message clearinghouse, so a subscription to their network might be required, but I'm not 100% on that.

Disclaimer, I work for Progress.

2016 EDIT: Artix (ADS) was sold to [C24](https://www.c24tech.com) sometime around the time this was originally written and is no longer a Progress product.  I am also no longer affiliated with either of these parties.

Comment: thanks but please read comment in buttom of @unapersson post.thanks

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT is the interbank messaging system used for transferring funds between banks. You don't access the database, you send messages. and security is very, very high, not surprisingly, but there are workrounds. I was once in the enviable  position of writing both the SWIFT messaging code for an IB, and the code that managed the bank's counterparties and settlement instructions. It was very tempting to insert  a few accounts of my own into the counterparty database (which was ours, not SWIFT's), but I resisted :-)

As for accessing it, it usually lives down the end of a socket. You can also get dedicated SWIFT terminals.

Comment: @unapersson : Thanks.I want to write a program for negotiation and settlement of an agreement.Is it poosible when I Issue an accounting voucher ,I create (for example) a MT700 message and place it some where that SWIFT terminal send it?

Comment: @Elinor You will have to ask the people responsible for the SWIFT implementation at your place of work. Typically, getting access to SWIFT is not easy.

Comment: @unapersson:in place that I work we have not people implementing SWIFT.but we have SWIFT terminals.please help me

Comment: @Elinor Sorry, I suggest you call SWIFT technical support.

Comment: I contact them but they do not answerd me :(

Answer (score 0):

It is worth visiting [swiftcommunity.net](https://www.swiftcommunity.net/) (which is owned and run by SWIFT) and visiting the forum on [Developers' Support](https://www.swiftcommunity.net/communities/63/detail) with any of your specific SWIFT related questions.

Comment: I register in swiftcommunity.net 2 month ago and they don't gave me credential to use sites features.:(